# Syntax error in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

We are working on our first site with Symfony. In development, everything works. But when we are on production, nothing works!
Trying to use `app_dev.php`, we see:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting
>   variable (T_VARIABLE)" in AbstractProxyFactory.php (line 72), script
>   of Doctrine (in composer.json, we ask for Doctrine > 2.5)

What does that mean?

Comment: It was just a problem of different versions of php (7.1.8 vs 7.0.27) !

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache for the production environment.

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Switch to the production environment with composer during deployment.

```
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```